# Javascript: Extract MAC codes from freeform text using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to write a Chrome Extension that will scan a web page for valid MAC codes and push each in to an array. I have a regex that validates the MAC but I can't get it to match multiple codes.

Here is a quick snippet of my code :

```
var regex = /^([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})$/;
var body = document.body.innerText.replace(/\n/g,' ');

console.log(body.match(regex));

var occur = regex.exec(body);

console.log(occur);
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Some sample please along with expected outputs.

Comment: what do you mean by multiple codes?

Comment: Bit difficult to give a sample at the moment. Imagine I have a webpage that contains the MAC addresses of all the routers that are currently connected to my network (I am an ISP). I would want to parse that page and pull off all the valid MAC codes. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MAC addresses are typically 6 groups of two hexadecimal digits (0-9,A,B,C,D,E,F), separated either by colons (:) or hyphens (-).

Are you looking for this?

```
/([0-9A-F]{2}(?:[:-][0-9A-F]{2}){5})/g
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/pF9oW8/4)

Get the matched group from index 1.

Comment: Brilliant! I should have joined here hours ago. Many many thanks.

Comment: updated the post to return only one match using Non-capturing group

Answer (score 1):

Remove the beginning of string `^` and end of string `$` anchors and use the `g` (*global*) modifier..

```
var regex = /([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})/g
```

As stated in the documentation...

> The **`g`** modifier is used to perform a global match (find all matches rather than stopping after the first match)